# Using derived type member as a do loop iteration variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran, derived-types

EDIT:  This has been marked as a duplicate of a question about using array elements to iterate a do loop.  A similar question to be sure, but you can read the answers and not see anything about using non-array members of derived types.  Even though the logic might be the same, it is not at all spelled out for anyone who doesn't already realize that the same logic applies.  So I think this is a distinct question.

This code will not compile under gfortran (version 5.2.0).  The compiler returns an "unclassifiable statement" error where marked:

```
module stuff

type foo
  integer :: bar
  contains
  procedure :: iterator
end type foo

contains

subroutine iterator(stuff_inst)

class(foo) :: stuff_inst
integer :: local_bar

do stuff_inst%bar=1,10      ! <--- error
  print *, stuff_inst%bar
enddo

end subroutine

end module stuff
```

This code compiles just fine and, with a driving program, runs OK too:

```
module stuff

type foo
  integer :: bar
  contains
  procedure :: iterator
end type foo

contains

subroutine iterator(stuff_inst)

class(foo) :: stuff_inst
integer :: local_bar

do local_bar=1,10                ! <--- no error
  stuff_inst%bar = local_bar     ! <--- no error
  print *, stuff_inst%bar
enddo

end subroutine

end module stuff
```

Could someone tell me the specific problem?  Is it not legal to use derived type members in a do loop iteration?  That's all I can think of, but I have searched and can't find any rule to that effect.

Comment: @francescalus  5.2.0

Comment: Looks like a compiler bug. Try a more recent version.

Comment: The linked question is about array elements, but the same logic applies for type components.

Comment: I don't even remember my own answers...And I must had it wrong that time as well.

Comment: Components (and function pointer results) fall foul of the same restriction as array elements.  While the component is a scalar variable, `stuff_inst%bar` isn't a scalar variable _name_.  You're going to need something like `i` (of `integer i`).  This is the point of the answer to the other question.

Comment: Regarding "Even though the logic might be the same, it is not at all spelled out for anyone who doesn't already realize that the same logic applies." - that's exactly why we can mark as a duplicate and keep this question around (as long as my expository comments remain).  Alternatively, I/someone can expand on the answers to that other question.

Comment: Indeed, why I'm also happy to vote up this question at the same time as closing it.

Comment: I've added an answer to the other question, kind of with a question myself: Could one use an `associate` construct to get around this limitation?

Comment: @francescalus  OK, fair enough.  Thanks.

Comment: I've added an answer to that other question which also covers components.  Please review that and let me know if you feel it doesn't cover this case adequately.

Comment: @francescalus  Very clear answer.  Thank you!