# gfortran Unclassifiable statment for type-bound loop variable

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a reason this produces an unclassifiable statement error on the line "do my_a%i = 1, 5"?

*mymod.f90*

```
module mymod                                                                                                                          
   type a                                                                                                                             
      integer :: i                                                                                                                    
   end type a                                                                                                                         
end module mymod
```

*main.f90*

```
program main                                                                                                                          
   use mymod, only : a                                                                                                                
   implicit none                                                                                                                      
   type(a) :: my_a                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                                                      
                                                                                                                                      
   do my_a%i = 1, 5                                                                                                                      
      print *, "hello"                                                                                                                
   enddo                                                                                                                              
end program main
```

Comment: `my_a%i` is not a _named variable_. The linked questions asks about an array element, but the reason these are not allowed is the same.

Comment: See also [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49907449/3157076).

Comment: Thanks! Appreciate it. I just used an associate construct.